# Asynchronously Running Synchronous Code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, async-await, task

Entity framework imports stored procedures as methods on your DbContext class.
However, they are not asynchronous and I want to be able to call these from an asynchronous WebApi controller without it blocking the thread. I have written an async wrapper method, but I am confused by a warning Visual Studio is giving me.

Will this code execute asynchronously?

```
    public async Task AttachTypeToMeetingTime(int meetingTimeId,int meetingTypeId)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //synchronous method generated by EF.
            //VS warning here
            AttachTypeToMeetingTime(meetingTimeId, meetingTypeId);
        });
    }
```

Visual studio gives me the warning:

> Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current thread continues before the call is completed

However If I follow the suggestion and add await it is underlined in red and will not compile.

Don't I want the current thread to continue before the call is completed?

Comment: Side note: I hope you understand that what you are actually trying to do only decreases performance - instead of having one thread from threadpool handling request you now shift work to another thread pool thread and pay for context switch/thread synchronization (in addition that thread also is not setup with culture/Current request and will give you all kinds of fun later)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry I've seen that before and I assumed it was ok.  Moved the resolution section to its own answer. how is what I am doing different from async controller methods and/or vanilla EF async methods like `FindAsync()`?

Comment: True async methods don't do busy wait on a thread (unlike synchronous once). You may want to read about async in general, [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) is one starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a recursive call. I don't think you meant to do that.

It should call a synchronous method like you said instead of **AttachTypeToMeetingTime**.

```
public async Task AttachTypeToMeetingTime(int meetingTimeId,int meetingTypeId)
{
   await Task.Run(() =>
   {
      SomeMethod(meetingTimeId, meetingTypeId);
        ^^^^^
   });
}
```

Comment: Good catch on the recursion

Comment: it was a typo, thank you for catching that.  I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I was calling the method name incorrectly.  It should be:

```
public async Task AttachTypeToMeetingTimeAsync(int meetingTimeId,int meetingTypeId)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //synchronous method generated by EF.
            //VS warning here
            AttachTypeToMeetingTime(meetingTimeId, meetingTypeId);
        });
    }
```

The signature for the generated method was

```
AttachTypeToMeetingTime(int? meetingTimeId,int? meetingTypeId)
```

I thought that because my method's parameters were `int` and the generated method's parameters were `int?` that the signatures would not clash, but I guess that trips up visual studio's suggestion engine and *maybe* the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Fill out the stuff that starts with "Your" in the code below.

```
public async Task AttachTypeToMeetingTime(int meetingTimeId,int meetingTypeId)
{
   using(var context = new YourContext())
   {
      await conext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("YourStoredProcedureName @YourParam1Name, @YourParam2Name", meetingTimeId, meetingTypeId);
   }
}
```